# Chronosphere interaction with slows and stuns

Tags: dota-2

Back in DotA 1, if Darkterror caught an unit affected by a slow/stun in Chronosphere, the slow/stun timer would pause, meaning the hero would be stunned/slowed for the remaining of its duration after chronosphere duration, due to the pause mechanic of Warcraft.

Not so long ago, I heard Dota 2 Chronosphere now work as a big AoE stun instead of pausing any buff/non-doom debuff duration. Is it true?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes it is true. In chronosphere your stuns will not stack.

Here a list of Chronosphere Ability taken from [gamepedia](http://dota2.gamepedia.com/Faceless_Void)

- Affects both units and buildings, both allies and enemies
- Couriers are unaffected.
- While in the Chronosphere, Faceless Void and any units he controls have 1000 movement speed and unitwalking.
- Enemy heroes do not have evasion while they are trapped in Chronosphere.
- Faceless Void and Void's illusions(Whether they're hostile or friendly) are not paused in Chronosphere.
- However if cast by another source (ex. Rubick), Chronosphere won't provide Faceless Void with 1000 movement speed and unitwalking. He will still receive double the damage coming from Time Lock occurring.
- Does not pause the map. Runes, Trees, and Creep spawns (Lane and Neutrals) persist within a Chronosphere.